# Not uploading pictures to Firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload pictures to storage. Every time I launch my emulator I get no errors and everything works perfectly except that when I select the pictures in my emulator and upload them it does not show in the Firebase Storage section even after I refresh. Here is my code:

```
    package com.safariagaming;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.safariagaming.mtc_project.R;

public class Account_Page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mSelectImage;

    private StorageReference mStorage;

    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account__page);

        mSelectImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectImage_BUTTON);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(); //.child at end ifyou want to add an child to it

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);


        mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

                intent.setType("image/*");

                startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                    Toast.makeText(Account_Page.this, "Upload Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }//you can also add onFaliure listener
            });


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put files to storage as a stream instead of an Uri

Remove the Uri part and put the following instead:

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```

and change the `putFile(uri)` with `putFile(inputStream)`
And also consider changing `uri.getLastPathSegment()` part with a reasonable file name such as `your_name.png`(Note that even if your photo is not in png format that will work based on my experience)
This should work

Comment: I tried what you said but get an error.


https://pastebin.com/GJyGw3tV

Maybe I misunderstood what you were trying to say

Comment: pastebin.com is forbidden in my country would you mind using other platform

Comment: I missed that but Android Studio should have warned you. You must put try-catch statement for input stream

Answer (score 0):

This is how i uploaded a image to storage

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(FILE_STORAGE_PATH);
InputStream stream = null;
try {
    stream = new FileInputStream(new File(uri.getLastPathSegment()));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
StorageReference photoRef = storageRef.child("Photos/" + image_name + ".jpg");
        UploadTask uploadTask = photoRef.putStream(stream);
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Success TO UPLOAD IMAGE");


            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(WorkCompletionActivity.this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                //Failure
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

That Code works perfectly for me.
Just change Rules in Firebase Console

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

and everything will works perfectly